# Client Authentication via X509 Certificates in asp.net in IIS 6.0

Tags: certificate, digital-signature

I am trying to read eToken certificate, unable to do so, this app is running ok in IDE, but when deployed at IIS 6.0, throwing error - current session is not interactive. Pl help. Thanx in adv.

Codes:

```
X509Certificate2 selcert = null; 
selcert = DSCLib32.UtilMethods.PickCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My);
```

Comment: Can you show some codes & certificate configurations?

Comment: X509Certificate2 selcert =   null;
        selcert = DSCLib32.UtilMethods.PickCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My);